# Make a DBGrid go to records based on a letter pressed

Tags: delphi, keyboard, keypress, dbgrid

Overall idea: mimic for example, pressing the 'c' key on the keyboard while on windows desktop  until you get to the 'Chrome' shortcut. Or when using a listbox, pressing the letter of the value you want instead of scrolling through the whole list. I want to be able to do this for a DBGrid, so I could press a letter to jump to the record that the first character of a string of a "name column" matches the key pressed.

Comment: Just use OnKeyPress on the grid and Locate on the dataset ...

Answer (score 1):

This is called `incremental search` and in the Embarcadero CodeCentral site exist a sample of how create a [`DBGrid - Incremental search / filter`](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27541)

Comment: This is close. Is there a way to do it exactly that way but without the tEdit?

Answer (score 0):

re your comment to RRUZ answer:

I tried to get it to work without a TEdit and gave up after several hours. I don't want to discourage you, though. I would be interested in such a solution as well. Depending on the exact use case, it might be enough to just catch the entries to the dbgrid and pass them on to an invisible TEdit which then triggers the lookup. (In my case this did not suffice.) You do this by adding a DBGrid1KeyPress method with the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  msg: TWMKey;
begin
  msg.CharCode := Ord(KEY);
  PostMessage(Edit1.Handle, WM_CHAR, Ord(key), 0);
end;
```

You will also have to remove doEditing from the grid's options and possibly switch it to ReadOnly.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it without having TEdit appearing on screen, is to add the following event snippets. The following code will work on top of the Embarcadero CodeCentral's code that was referred previously by RRUZ:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
if Key=VK_BACK then
    begin
      Edit1.Text := copy(Edit1.Text,1,length(Edit1.Text)-1);
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.DBGrid1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
if Key in ['a'..'z'] + ['A'..'Z']  then
  begin
      Edit1.Text := Edit1.Text + Key;
  end;
end;
```

You can then set the Edit box invisible. All you need is to focus on the list and press keys.